# Two well-orderings of an infinite cardinal agree on a large set (Part II)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This is a follow-up to [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146111/two-well-orderings-of-an-infinite-cardinal-agree-on-a-large-set) on the Kunen exercise, which asks for a proof that any two well-orderings on an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ agree on a set of size $\kappa$.  I'm perfectly willing to accept proofs that use choice and I understand how to use transfinite recursion to get the result for regular cardinals.

The proof I've seen that I come closest to understanding is the [answer given by Jason Palumbo here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40507/distinct-well-orderings-of-the-same-set).  He notes that the problem is equivalent to showing that if $f:\kappa \to \kappa$ is bijective, then there is a set $A \subseteq \kappa$ on which $f$ is increasing.

If $\kappa$ is singular, it is the limit of (successor) cardinals $\lambda_\alpha$ with cofinality greater than $\operatorname{cf} \kappa$.

Let $f: \kappa \to \kappa$ be a bijection.  Then $\exists A_1 \subseteq \lambda_1$ with $f$ increasing on $A_1$..  Define $\gamma_1 = \sup f(A_1)$.

Here's the step I don't understand.  Jason states that $\operatorname{cf} \gamma_1 = \operatorname{cf} \lambda_1 \gt \operatorname{cf} \kappa$.  I don't see why the first equality has to hold.  If it is the case, it follows that $\gamma_1 \lt \kappa$ and we can complete the proof by recursion.

So if someone would be kind enough to explain this for me, I'd very much appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need choice? This statement is absolute. Might as well do it in $L[A,B]$ where $A$ and $B$ are the two well-orders.

Comment: Much of the discussion in the questions I linked was about proving the statement with or without using choice.  I'm just saying that if it's a proof that I can understand, then it's not important to me to go out of my way to avoid using choice.  For example, the proof outlined above does use choice.

As a reminder, I've been out of the field for nearly 30 years (I'm now a business litigator) and relatively recently decided to start working my way through Kunen's book for fun.